# Optimizing background gif for mobile phones?

Tags: html, css, mobile, optimization, gif

So, I have a gif running, that takes up the whole screen, as a background. How ever, when I checked the site on my phone, the whole screen wasn't filled up and half way down was just black. http://goroam.org here's the link, how would I make this where phones would have it where the gif takes up the whole screen,and the text is in the middle just like if I was viewing the site from a laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution..

Making background-size: 100% 100%; will make image full to screen

And make h1 responsive to screen so it auto adjust screen..

Here is Code:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    color: #EEEEEE;
    font: 24px/1.3 "arial";
    min-height: 100%;
    background: url("http://media.giphy.com/media/13bGgH9VnEDsuA/giphy.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / 100% 100% #000000;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

h1 {
    color: #F0F0F0;
    font-family: "belta bold";
    font-size: 212px;
    left: 0;
    margin: -120px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you want perfect solution use css media queries..

Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/53zaT/

Using media Queries

```
@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
   h1{
   font-size:62px;
   margin-top:-31px;
}
}
```

Here is fiddle using media queries http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/53zaT/2/

Hope this hepls you :)